# Pandas verify if value and date value set

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterrows in pandas and need to figure out if a values are set in that row.

issue is not NaN and that d_date is an actual date.

```
d_action   d_shares          issue    d_price  d_comm   d_date  
0      NaN      NaN            NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN   
1      NaN      NaN          AT&T INC    NaN      0     NaN   
2      Rcd       70          AT&T INC   34.57     0     2013-09-16 00:00:00
```

I am getting several different errors trying both .notnull and .notna mostly related to a string error.

```
if row.issue.notna () and row.d_date.notna ()
```

this gives me 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'

not sure how to verify if it is an actual date? Would settle for not NaN.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[isna and notna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) are your friends, for your problem, try:

```
pd.isna(frame['d_price']) and pd.isna(d['d_date'])
```

You should be sorted, leave a comment if you aren't.

Comment: for index, row in df2.iterrows ():

Answer (score 0):

```
if pd.notna(row.issue) and pd.notna(row.d_date) :
```